# Collecting state from multiple child tabs

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we want to create a new `Task`. We have 2 categories of information we want to collect from the user for creating a new `Task`: `general params`, `action params`.
 To make it easily separated we are separating between them with tabs. so each gets its own react component, both stored in different `react-tabs` tabs.

In the parent component I have a `save` button and I want that at any given time, the user could click it to send the entire state from both the tabs' state to the server.

While I could forward event handlers from the parent to the children (as suggested by other questions on this topic)... doing it for each of the 20 controls (dropdowns, textfields, date time pickers) in each of them requires a lot of boilerplate code and seems unreasonable.

I'm looking for a best practice for this situation. Thanks!

Comment: I think your best bet here is to use a store library such as redux which gives a simple solution to that kind of logic

Comment: I have redux in my app, and I thought it's meant when I need to share state between separate components in my app. I can consider using it for this case, but my problem will still happen: I'd still need to create 20x redux's actions (which includes a const 'DROPDOWN1_CHANGED' for each, among other boilerplate code)